# twisted server cannot connect over internet

Tags: twisted, python-3.4, linux-mint

I have written server (I've used python 3, twisted, tkinter) and everything is Okay when I try to connect to it on my local machine, for example via telnet I do so - "telnet localhost port", but when I try this "telnet ip_address port" it's not going to be connected. Question is why? And to simplify this, here's simple code:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol

class Echo(protocol.Protocol):

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self.transport.write(data)

def main():
    factory = protocol.ServerFactory()
    factory.protocol = Echo
    reactor.listenTCP(8123, factory)
    reactor.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an overview of what needs to be done. To start things off, you have to bind to an interface other than localhost. Alternatively, you can listen on all interfaces (ie. `interface = '0.0.0.'`). In your code, you need to append the interface to your `reactor.listenTCP()` function:

```
reactor.listenTCP(8123, factory, interface='0.0.0.0')
```

Next you will have to ensure incoming TCP traffic is permitted on your router and server. You will also have to forward traffic from your incoming WAN interface from your router to the interface on your server. On the server side, you'll have to ensure incoming traffic is permitted by your firewall(s). So let's say your WAN IP address provided by your ISP is `72.10.20.30` and your Twisted server is running on server's interface `192.168.1.100:8123`. Go onto your router and look for Port Forward or NAT functions then set them so that requests for your WAN IP are forwarded to your server's IP.

Take extra precautions with these steps as this can leave your network very vulnerable! It's probably better to use services like OpenShift or Heroku to host your Python projects.

Comment: thanks for your respond, but it still doesn't work. I set `interface='0.0.0.0'` and I did 'port forwarding' (and I'm running on Linux Mint, guess I have no firewall(s)). When I scan port 8123 on my IP for example here - [link](http://www.canyouseeme.org/) port is closed, what's wrong?

Comment: Does your ISP allow incoming TCP connections? Some don't

Comment: Maybe, do not know how to check it. But now I'm wondering how does Skype work when someone is trying to call me? Or torrent (peer-to-peer connection), maybe there is good article or book to clarify it, I'd read it.

Comment: Try pinging your WAN IP with [this site](http://ping.eu/ping/) if the pings fail then you'll either have to adjust some of your router security settings until it works or call your ISP. Usually an incoming connections work over an established connection. So you if you establish an outgoing connection first, then an incoming connection can be made using the same IP. As for Skype, I'm sure you connect to a central server and your pc is the client.